# Not able to slide the div content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to move the images inside a div to the left one by one.But i'm only able to move one image on click of a button.I'm looking to slide the images inside a div.
Here is my code on jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/K2JBg/

Comment: You did not specified: **What will happen once the slider reaches the last image?**

Comment: ya i know...but for now all i want is to slide the first image so that the second one comes into display......i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2JBg/2/)*

- Once you reach the last image it would be goot to turn your slider to the starting position, so let's use *Modulus* to turn our counter to '0'.
- Than just move your slider doing some basic math: `-300px * the current Counter value`.

After each click counter will increase, but once it reaches the number of images `4` it will jump back to value `0` - `300px * 0 = 0` and that will slide your gallery back to '0px' left.

jQuery:

```
var imgN = $('#slide div img').length; // number of images
var c = 0; // just a Counter
$("#btn").click(function() {
    c = ++c % imgN;      // once it reaches the imgN will turn to '0'
    $("#slide div").animate({left: -300*c }, "fast");   // let's use our math!
});
```

Modified CSS:

```
    #slide{
        height: 300px;
        width:300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
    #slide div{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top:0px;
        width:9000px;    /*make sure to have a big value here if you don't want to do it dynamically with jQUery*/
    }
   #slide img{
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        float:left;
    }
```